# Is this an acceptable "recursive" concurrency design

Tags: java, recursion, concurrency

I want to process some data in parallel worker threads. But instead of a parent thread that checks if one worker thread has finished and then assigning a new task, I want the threads to load the data themselfs and to restart themselfes again.

Now this is what I came up with:

```
public class MainApp {

ExecutorService executor;


public synchronized void runNewWorkerThread(){

    //load the data to be processed in the threads from a file 

    executor.submit(()->{
        try{
            // process data (unstable)
        }catch(Exception e){
            //catch and log exception
        }finally{
            runNewWorkerThread();
        }

    });


}
```

}

now this recursivly restarts the worker threads.Is this an acceptable design, or should I rather keep the worker threads alive by doing some kind of a loop inside the runnable?

If this is an acceptable design, which ExecutorService would you reccomend me to use, and why ?

Thanks a lot,
 Flo

Edit: The number of Threads started is fixed, because in the threads a fixed number of real devices is automated. However there is one single list the threads need to load their data from,sequentially.

Comment: If you have to implement a repeating task you should use a loop, otherwise you'll run into `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: oh, thought I would avoid that by the fact, that a new Task is executed and the old on terminates

Comment: That depends on the `Executor`. There won’t be a recursion, if the executor’s submit method always processes jobs asynchronously, but then, there is still no benefit in doing it this way instead of a loop.

Comment: well thank you. I think Im going for a loop now. That seems more reasonable. Which ExecutorService should I use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is fine. Also, you should not run into a `StackOverflowException`, since you do not call the method `runNewWorkerThread` directly. You just submit the code to call the `runNewWorkerThread` to the `ExecutorService` and the `submit` function call will return pretty much instantly (depending on the implementation).

Be sure to start the worker properly. If you want e.g. five threads to run in parallel, you need to call the `runNewWorkerThread` method five times, because every call to `runNewWorkerThread` will start only exactly one new `runNewWorkerThread` after it is finished. Also, you should only have one `MainApp` object, to ensure the `synchronized` keyword really synchronizes all load operations.

---

**Update**

If you use e.g. the [newFixedThreadPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-) you can be sure to not run into a `StackOverflowException`, because this `ExecutorService` only runs a fixed number of threads at a time. That means, that it will only execute another submitted task, after one of the other task is finished. Because the other task is finished, it must have left the `runNewWorkerThread` method. I hope this is clear enough?

Comment: So can I be sure running a new worker thread starts a new stack ? So I wont run into a SOF ?

Comment: The point of said executor is not the number of threads but the fact that it uses an *unbounded queue*. So even if there is no available thread, you are guaranteed that the new job gets enqueued and never executed on the caller’s stack. Problems can only arise with executors having a bounded queue and something like a [`CallerRunsPolicy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy.html). So to say it explicitly, yes, with an executor produced by `newFixedThreadPool` you can’t get a stackoverflow when submitting jobs from a job.